# Are the curly braces in this code referred to as an anonymous function

Tags: kotlin

I came across the following code:

```
class SalutationConverter : EnumTypeConverter<Salutation>({ enumValueOf(it) })
```

Are the curvy braces {} referred to as an "anonymous function" in Kotlin?

The declaration for EnumTypeConverter looks like this:

```
open class EnumTypeConverter<T : Enum<T>>(private val enumValueOfParser: ((String) -> T)) {

    @TypeConverter
    fun enumTypeToString(taxType: T?): String? = taxType?.name

    @TypeConverter
    fun stringToEnum(taxType: String?): T? = taxType?.let { enumValueOfParser(it) }
}
```

Comment: An anonymous function is one that in which it's name is omitted (parameter types can be omitted if they can be inferred from context), and parameters are always passed inside parentheses. So to answer your question, no the curly braces are no indication of a function being anonymous.

Comment: Then what would you refer the curly braces to in this code?

Comment: The way I read it would be it passes function arguments `( ... )` and executes an expression inside of it `{ ... }`. Similar somewhat to an anonymous function, but I think it's more of a Lamba expression. https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/kotlin-for-py/functional-programming.html#function-literals-lambda-expressions-and-anonymous-functions

Comment: Isn't the constructor parameter for EnumTypeConverter considered a lambda function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Are the curvy braces {} referred to as an "anonymous function" in Kotlin?

No, they are referred to as a [*Lambda Expression*](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#lambda-expressions-and-anonymous-functions). An [*Anonymous Function*](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#anonymous-functions) is declared with the `fun` keyword just like a named function, except leaving out the name:

```
fun(x: Int, y: Int): Int {
    return x + y
}
```

Note that curly braces do not necessarily denote a *Lambda Expression*. They could also denote a *Block*, i.e. in this example:

```
fun add(x: Int, y: Int): Int {
    return x + y
}
```

Comment: How do you call an anonymous function if it has no name?

Comment: @AndroidDev, you assign it to variable: `val f = fun(...`

Comment: The same way you refer to an anonymous object: assign it to a variable, pass it as an argument, immediately call it like this: `(fun(x: Int, y: Int): Int { return x + y })(2, 3)`, etc.